# How to detect out of gas errors on internal transactions without a return?

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging, out-of-gas

I was working on the 13th level of [Ethernaut](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0x9b261b23cE149422DE75907C6ac0C30cEc4e652A) when I discovered that calling a function of a contract with an explicit amount of gas results in a revert with no further description, even though the cause of revert was too little gas being passed to the function being called. The following example illustrates this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract GatekeeperOne {

  address public entrant;

  function enter() public {
    entrant = tx.origin;
  }
  
  function debugEnter() external {
      this.enter{gas: 1}();
  }
}
```

When I compile this with the v0.6.12 compiler and run debugEnter(), [etherscan reports](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xcf4cb586fb89dedd4e2d6ee7db191b6e3fc7da18436984c40c0a2870afdbd510) only a revert error, and says nothing about running out of gas. I understand the recommended way to detect this is to return a bool regarding the success of the function, but how can I detect this if calling a contract that I have no control over?

This is a related question, it seems that it is not even possible to catch the error and handle the case of too little gas being passed on: [Catch Internal Out of Gas Exception in Solidity Code](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/83836/)

Answer (score 0):

You can access `Geth Debug Trace_2` from Etherscan (in right top corner hamburger button), which shows all the calls and the result of each of them. This [link](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0xcf4cb586fb89dedd4e2d6ee7db191b6e3fc7da18436984c40c0a2870afdbd510&type=gethtrace2) is the result of clicking on debug trace for your mentioned tx, where you can see the `out of gas` error.

```
  "type": "CALL",
  "from": "0x07475a9a0866345684f4c8753e6d040e30b74f66",
  "to": "0x35b525d253beb7a8a044ab679deaae11cb02d8b5",
  "value": "0x0",
  "gas": "0x2d7478",
  "gasUsed": "0x1cf",
  "input": "0x0c303c89",
  "error": "execution reverted",
  "time": "1.9999ms",
  "calls": [
    {
      "type": "CALL",
      "from": "0x35b525d253beb7a8a044ab679deaae11cb02d8b5",
      "to": "0x35b525d253beb7a8a044ab679deaae11cb02d8b5",
      "value": "0x0",
      "input": "0xe97dcb62",
      "error": "out of gas"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you also detect this case from the code? eg. to handle it within solidity?

Comment: @Griffin Solidity supports try-catch blocks as mentioned in [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/78563/), but I'm not sure you can catch `out of gas`. There is also another [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/83836/) about handling this error, which is unfortunately unanswered.